# How to load contents from different directory for www.website.com

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

How to display contents from `www` directory for `http://www.website.com`

i..e when a user visits `http://www.website.com` i want to display the contents from `/www` directory but keep the url same.

I have tried few methods, but for all of them the url changes as well....

Though i want to load the content from `http://www.website.com/www/` i want to keep the url as `http://www.website.com/`

And same for other pages., i..e `http://www.website.com/products.php` : `/www/products.php`

Comment: Why don't you modify your document root?

Comment: I tried doing this via htaccess, but it didn't work, Can you suggest any htaccess tutorial for this?

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what exactly did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running apache, you can change the root folder in the httpd.conf file (UserDir)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir

So you would have to do something like:

> UserDir /www/

Comment: Is there any way to do this via htaccess?

Comment: I didn't know myself, but after some googling I arrived on this link you could try: http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?402-Redirect-Root-Directory&s=bb49150d81f3e8103f6082a6223e3101&p=2418#post2418

Comment: Hey, is there any way you can help me out with another problem, The given code works perfectly., what i want to do now is, redirect all other sub-domain request to /application directory but i don't want to display the folder name in the url, just like this one, What will be code for this? (both of this integrated together)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

# Only apply to website.com URLs outside the www folder, but ignore real files and folders
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1

# Finally redirect the topmost folder itself
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www/index.php [L]
```